# Why we use 'bubbles' in flex events

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, custom-event

I've doubt when we create custom event in flex.

Why do we use 'type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false' these parameter in flex events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bubbling** causes a dispatched event to continue to be dispatched up the display tree until it reaches the stage.  This is useful in various scenarios.

For example: Imagine you have several buttons inside a parent DisplayObject.  You could add listeners to each button, and remember to remove them afterwards, or you could just add one listener to the parent.  This works because MouseEvents have bubbling enabled.

```
buttonParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleButtonClick);

function handleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("The button clicked was " + event.target.name);
}
```

The benefit of this is that you can now add and remove buttons freely, without having to worry about attaching listeners to them.  The `target` property of the event object will be a reference to the button that was clicked, and `currentTarget` will be a reference to the parent.

**Cancelable** is a flag that sets whether or not you are permitted to stop the default action of an event by calling the `preventDefault()` method.

Comment: For objects that never get added to the display list, such as data objects, the bubbles parameter does nothing.

Please also note that the code above will trace the name of the button _parent_, not the button, because currentTarget always points to the object whose addEventListener code was called.  If you want to get the button's name, you'd need to set mouseChildren to false on the button and trace event.target.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - I always seem to get those the wrong way round.